# Image captured on custom camera with GPS not being saved on Android 7.1.1+

Tags: android, camera, gallery, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.1-nougat

I have already requested the permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest and also checked that I have write permissions when running.

When I test with Oreo the folder and teh temporary file is created but the problem is it is not entering to the section where i am trying to write the image bytes to file.

I am getting this problem only in Android 7.1.1+. Up to Android 7.0 it works fine. I have checked on a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 and Google Pixel XL 2. I am using a custom camera with with GPS and the following code:

```
This is the code i am using and the problem here in oreo is it is not entering to imagereader section ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener. I got the problem by giving some alerts. So is there anyone to help me to find out why it is not entering to imagereader section?
```

String dateTimeOrg= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date()).toString();

```
    try {
        file = createTemporaryFile(dateTimeOrg, ".jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final File finalFile = file;
    //end old working code

    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                buffer.get(bytes);

                // Need to remove it
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Going to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                toast.show();
                //End Need to remove it

                save(bytes);
            }
```

The following is the code to save the image

```
OutputStream output = null;
try {
    output = new FileOutputStream(finalFile);
    output.write(bytes);
} finally {
    if (null != output) {
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `there is a corrupted image file in it`. Then why do you suggest that it is not being saved?

Comment: the corrupted image file is on the folder that i am creating. In my code before saving an image i am creating a temporary image with new name and then writing the camera captured bytes to this image file. I didn't paste the full code here because it is a lengthy one. I have placed the code above is writing that bytes to image file, that is not working. And also here in my place i didn't get an Oreo device to debug. When I am checking eimulator then it is working but when i give to my client with oreo device they are saying it is not saving images.

Comment: Unclear: is it not saving to file or is the file corrupted? Come to the point please.

Comment: `i am creating a temporary image with new name `. You did not post the code where you do that. But then you should not already create a a file as new FileOutputStream will create the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, First i am creating a temporary file and then i am trying to write the bytes of image to that file. It is allowing me to create a folder and to create a temp file with a new name and extension jpg. At first that file is blank. Then i am trying to write the captured image bytes with the function save(bytes) and the code to save that bytes to the  created file is given as output = new FileOutputStream(finalFile);
    output.write(bytes);  but in oreo it is not happening it is working fine upto android 7.0 and my app is at playstore with version working fine upto 7.0

Comment: You told nothing new. I already knew that you created an empty file. I said that you should not create an empty file to begin with. But you did not comment on that.

Comment: I am creating a temporary file to save the image captured and i am writing the bytes to that file. You can see the code below, and I understood where the problem is happening. It is not entering to the imagereader section, I am posting my code as a new section because the comment not allows me to post the code fully

Comment: So, your capture request did not work. Maybe you should disclose how you perform this request?

Comment: `am creating a temporary file` YOU SHOULD NOT DO THAT!

Comment: `I am posting my code as a new section ` Well you did not. You posted it as an answer. Please remove your answer and add the code in a new block of your post. In a new 'section' if you want to call it like that.

Comment: i have edited my post above and pasted the full code there. I am not able to delete the answer. I am posting this question to get help from someone because i am stuck with this position from many days